# Save the session data before being destroyed?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, php-5.3

Is it possible to save the session data for database purposes before being destroyed?

For instance, I have the data below from a session,

```
// start session
session_start();

// init session var
if (!isset($_SESSION['images'])) $_SESSION['images'] = array();

array
  0 => 
    array
      'image_id' => int 1
      'image_title' => string 'test 1' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array
      'image_id' => int 2
      'image_title' => string 'test 2' (length=6)
```

And I want to send it to database when the session is destroyed or when the browser is closed.

```
if(unset($_SESSION['images']))
{
    // do something?
}
```

Is it feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should think of `session_start();` as creating a single cookie on your browser with a hash that matches a session file on the server, the server will place any data into the $_SESSION whilst your "session" is active, once you close the browser that cookie is discarded from your browser, and eventually(a clean-up invoked by a cron) the session file is removed from the server.

If you want to store persistent data for a time period or user then you should store it in the database, a cache file, memcache or such.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually manage your sessions with [session_set_save_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) which sets user-level session storage functions. Then you can handle your session shutdown via [session_register_shutdown()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register-shutdown.php).

Here is an interesting test of this capability: http://www.rooftopsolutions.nl/blog/160

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at custome session handlers at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if(unset($_SESSION['images']))
{
    // do something?
}
```

This does not work as intended by you (being executed when the variable is unset). Instead it will just sucessfully unset your session variable and execute the `// do something` part.